# Angular 5 Structural Directive

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a reusable search box component currently my setup is this.

**search.component.html**

```
<div class="search-box-container">
  <fa-icon class="search-icon" [icon]="faSearch"></fa-icon>
  <input type="search" name="search" class="search-box" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```

**search.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  faSearch = faSearch;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and I want to use it accross multiple components like this:

`<app-search [ngModel]="searchString" (onUpdate)="updateSearch"></app-search>`

My question is how do I access the parent ngModel and onUpdate set in the main component inside of a structured component.

Comment: In your main component, you just bind to your search component's public properties with @Output decorator.

Comment: I am not sure but It seems your question is a little bit confusing. Can you illustrate your problem a little bit more (the last sentence). What do you mean with parent ngModel and onUpdate? You passed ngModel as properties so in app-search you would have 2 fields, @Input() ngModel and @Output onUpdate? Did I understand it wrong?

Comment: @StanisalvDontsov perfect that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Stanisalv answered in comments:

> In your main component, you just bind to your search component's public properties with `@Output` decorator.